# Do smart pointers work with arrays allocated using new T[]?

Tags: c++, c++11, new-operator, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

How do smart pointers handle arrays? For example,

```
void function()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> my_array(new int[5]);
}
```

When `my_array` goes out of scope and gets destructed, does the entire integer array get re-claimed? Is only the first element of the array reclaimed? Or is there something else going on (such as undefined behavior)?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

It will call `delete[]` and hence the entire array will be reclaimed but I believe you need to indicate that you are using an array form of `unique_ptr`by:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> my_array(new int[5]);
```

This is called as **Partial Specialization** of the `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Trivia:  This is where this syntax got invented: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/browse_thread/thread/469fcc136b8f2d42/59c0491245293db7?q=%3Cchar%5B%5D%3E+group:comp.lang.c%2B%2B+author:hinnant

Comment: @Howard Hinnant: Thanks for the trivia, I did'nt knew about it. You are the one who invented it, way back in 2001! That is so cool to have you around in here :)

Comment: That's also the only method which makes any sense, consider `typedef int (three_ints)[3]; template<typename T> void function(void) { unique_ptr<T> p(new T); } function<three_ints>();`

Comment: @Als:  I get credit for getting it standardized.  Luca (no, I don't know who Luca is) gets credit for inventing it, just by asking the right question. :-)

Comment: Are you certain `std::~unique_ptr<int[]>()` actually would call `delete []` rather than `delete`? I am not really sure...

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore: The C++ standard says so and it is the ultimate authority on C++ so my answer is yes, I am certain.

Comment: It's a shame this technique can't be used to declare arrays of pointer to abstract base class. or perhaps I am confusing an array of objects with an array of pointers..?

Answer (score 6):

Edit: This answer was wrong, as explained by the comments below.  Here's what I originally said:

> I don't think std::unique_ptr knows to call delete[].  It effectively
>   has an int* as a member -- when you delete an int* it's going to
>   delete the entire array, so in this case you're fine.
>
> The only purpose of the delete[] as opposed to a normal delete is that
>   it calls the destructors of each element in the array.  For primitive
>   types it doesn't matter.

I'm leaving it here because I learned something -- hope others will too.

Comment: If you use `new[]` you should use `delete[]` and `std::unique_ptr` is smart enough to handle this as well as many other improvements which is why it will replace `std::auto_ptr` soon.

Comment: -1 : `delete` must always and only be used with `new`; similarly `delete[]` must always and only be used with `new[]`. See C++2003, section 5.3.5 (expr.delete), para 2.

Comment: @Nathan: It does matter. Its not just the destructor. The memory allocation routines depend on you deleting the memory with the matching allocation method. Thus new/delete and new[]/delete[] are matched pairs.