# Create a double pointer (ptr to ptr) to std::pair with boost

Tags: c++, boost, double-pointer

I have the following code which I want to rewrite to make use of smart pointers:
I'm struggling to find any decent examples of how to declare, allocate memory and access the double pointer. Can anyone provide an example? I have read that shared_ptr is not the way to go because it uses delete instead of delete[], does shared_array need to be used?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_array.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    std::pair<int,float> **corrArray;   
    int rows=10;
    int cols=5;

    corrArray = new std::pair<int,float>*[rows];
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        corrArray[i] = new std::pair<int,float>[cols];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<cols; j++) {
            corrArray[i][j].first = i+j;
            std::cout << std::setw(3) << corrArray[i][j].first << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        delete[] corrArray[i];  
    }
    delete[] corrArray;
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: corrArray must be declared first (it will be a class member)

Comment: By "double pointer" you mean "pointer to pointer", not "pointer to `double`", yes?

Comment: Yes, I mean pointer to pointer

Comment: Just my 2 cents: I'd go with either writing my own class for your 2d-structure of your pairs (including a proper destructor), or with `vector < vector < pair <int,float> > >`.

Comment: Won't vector disappear when out of scope?

Comment: Yes, but so do raw pointers and smart pointers (the latter taking their pointees with them, the former leaving their pointees somewhere between purgatory and hell if you don't have other references to them). Keeping your objects alive as long as you need is your job (although I personally find that this most often occurs naturally).

Answer (score 0):

**Boost shared_ptr already works with arrays:**

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm

> Starting with Boost release 1.53, shared_ptr can be used to hold a pointer to a dynamically allocated array.

```
shared_ptr<double[1024]> p1( new double(1024) );
shared_ptr<double[]> p2( new double(n) );
```

**Boost shared_ptr is part of C++11 (so you could use those as well):**

[smart pointers and arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713484/smart-pointers-and-arrays)

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> my_array(new int[5]);
```

**Even better, use vector because you're not sharing it at all:**

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int,float>>> corrArray;
```

Comment: You missed the point - I want to declare a shared_array as a private class variable and then allocate memory to it later. Not all in one go...

Comment: @user2089851 Read up on the methods of `shared_ptr`; you can use `reset()` to change what it's pointing to later. With `vector` it's even better because you can "allocate" - `push_back` - later.