# c++ convert a pointer to a class into a instance of a class

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Imagine, I have some class :

```
class MyClass{
    public:
        MyClass(unsigned int N): a(new double[N]){};
        ~MyClass(){delete[] a;};

    private:
         double* a;
}
```

In another class, i use a pointer to this class :

```
class MyOtherClass{
    public:
        MyOtherClass(unsigned int N):p(new MyClass(N)){};
        ~MyOtherClass(){delete p;};

        MyClass* get_MyClass(){return p;};

    private:
        MyClass *p;
}
```

Then, in the main I need to get MyClass which is contained in MyOtherClass

```
int main(){
    MyOtherClass moc(1e100);
    MyClass mc;

    mc <-> moc.get_MyClass();
}
```

the `<->` is where I'm stuck. I want that `mc` becomes what p points to but without copying the (huge) static array. Is there a way to do this conversion efficiently ?

## Edit

thanks for your answers but i will precise something. as the time consuming part of the copy of MyClass comes from the copy of the static array, i thought i could do something like :

```
class MyClass{
    public:
        MyClass(unsigned int N): a(new double[N]),del(true){};
        MyClass(MyClass* mc): a(mc.get_a()),del(true){};
        ~MyClass(){if(del){delete[] a;}};

        double* get_a(){
            del = false;
            return a;
        }

    private:
         double* a;
         bool del;
}
```

with the main :

```
int main(){
    MyOtherClass moc(1e100);
    MyClass mc(moc.get_MyClass());
}
```

but i don't know if i will have memory leaks...

Answer (score 3):

Use reference:

```
int main(){
    MyOtherClass moc(1e100);
    MyClass& mc = *moc.get_MyClass();
}
```

With reference you can avoid the copying and still avoid using pointer syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want `p` contents destroyed, write a move constructor for `MyClass`.

In general, storing raw pointers like you do is problematic in general. If you used `vector<double>` instead, the whole task would be much easier, because in this approach unnecessary use of pointers is only adding you problems.

That's how I'd do that:

```
class MyClass{
    std::vector<double> a;
public:
    MyClass(unsigned int N): a(N) { }
    // no destructor!
};

class MyOtherClass{
    MyClass p;
public:
    MyOtherClass(unsigned int N) : p(N) {};
    // no destructor!!

    MyClass& getMyClass() { return p; };
}
```

Now it can be clearly seen you can't just use `getMyClass` to initialize new `MyClass` without copying, because it's a reference. However, if you are sure you won't need to use MyOtherClass later, or perhaps you just want to "steal" its data,  you should be able to safely `move` it out the `MyOtherClass`:

```
MyClass(MyClass&& other) : a(std::move(other.a)) {
    // now, I am not sure what will be left in other.a, but you can clean it up
    // (you can because it's in valid, only undefined state)
    other.a = std::vector<double>();
}
```

If you are not interested in stealing the data, but want to just access it, use, as others suggested, a reference.

Comment: thanks but i have to use static arrays... the code i use has been developed by someone else and i can't afford the rewriting of everything... but yeah, what i want is to "steal" datas...

Answer (score 0):

You should change the return type of

```
MyClass* get_MyClass(){return p;};
```

to

```
MyClass& get_MyClass(){return p;};
```

because what you described seems to be the main usage of this function.

Then just retrieve the instance with :

```
MyClass& mc = moc.get_MyClass ();
```

Comment: Careful: both do not do exactly the same.

Comment: @juanchopanza Could you please tell me the difference, as I can't seem to find any ?

Comment: @Jerska The first one will invoke the copy constructor of MyClass.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, `double* MyClass::a;` array could not be copied because of default copy constructor/copy operator performs just reassign of a pointers;

You should use smart pointer to wrap your `double* MyClass::a` variable to enable reference count and prevent execute delete operator twice on same addr inside of destructor.

You should navigate to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) and read about.

How to use smart pointer with array you can found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713484/smart-pointers-and-arrays)