# a function which convert integer to an array of digits c++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int *Arr(int y,int size){
int arg[size];
for(int i=size-1;i>=0;i--){
    arg[i]=y%10;
    y=y/10;
}
return arg;
}
int main(){
int *p=Arr(2587,4);
for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
  cout<<p[j]<<"   ";
}
return 0;
}

> Blockquote
```

I dont why this isn't working ...I'm trying to back an array but the problem is in the second digits.Can somebody help ;) thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are putting your result into a local array that is destroyed when the function ends. You need to dynamicaly allocate the array so that its life-span is not limited to the function it was created in:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int *Arr(int y, int size)
{
    // This local array will be destroyed when the function ends
    // int arg[size];

    // Do this instead: allocate non-local memory
    int* arg = new int[size];

    for(int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        arg[i] = y % 10;
        y = y / 10;
    }
    return arg;
}

int main()
{
    int *p = Arr(2587, 4);
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        cout << p[j] << "   ";
    }

    // You need to manually free the non-local memory
    delete[] p; // free memory

    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:**

Allocating dynamic memory using `new` is to be avoided if possible. You may want to study up on **smart pointers** for managing it.

Also, in real `C++` code, you would use a container like `std::vector<int>` rather than a builtin array

Comment: Standard containers manage dynamically allocated arrays (or collections of multiple objects, more generally), whereas smart pointers generally manage the lifetime of a single dynamically allocated object (not an array).   Making a smart pointer manage a dynamically allocated array causes undefined behaviour when the smart pointer cleans up.

Comment: @Peter `std::unique_ptr` handles arrays using a specialization: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6713515/3807729 [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Comment: Also `std::shared_ptr` can handle arrays if provided with a custom deleter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13062069/3807729

Comment: Fair enough.   That's new to me, so thanks for that.   Albeit, from the link, a unique_ptr<int> will not handle an array, but a unique_ptr<int []> will.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is not working.

At best, the behaviour is undefined, since `Arg()` is returning the address of a local variable `(arg)` that no longer exists for `main()`.   `main()` uses that returned address when it is not the address of anything that exists as far as your program is concerned.

There is also the incidental problem that `int arg[size]`, where `size` is not fixed at compile time, is not valid C++.  Depending on how exacting your compiler is (some C++ compilers reject constructs that are not valid C++, but others accept extensions like this) your code will not even compile successfully.

To fix the problem, have your function return a `std::vector<int>`  (`vector` is templated container defined in the standard header `<vector>`).   Then all your function needs to do is add the values to a local vector, which CAN be returned safely by value to the caller.

If you do it right, you won't even need to use a pointer anywhere in your code.